# What is the compatible version of mysql-connector-java-<XXX>.jar with jdk-11.0.15.1?

Tags: java, mysql, java-11

Application with jdk-11.0.15.1 is unable to connect with MySQL database using mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar. while the same was working till jdk-11.0.11.
Any compatible version issue ?

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:833)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:342)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:203)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1353)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:170)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:383)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:317)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:333)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Can you connect with a mysql client?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version? The error indicates that Java and MySQL cannot complete the TLS handshake, which generally means you're using an old MySQL version that uses an SSL/TLS version no longer enabled on Java, or only supports ciphersuites that are not supported (or disabled for security reasons) in Java.

Comment: 5.7.12 MYSQL Community Server

Comment: 5.7.12 is a bit old. You should better upgrade to 5.7.38. What TLS versions MySQL supports also depends on the installed or used OpenSSL version. If OpenSSL is too old only TLS 1.0 will be available.

Comment: OpenSSL installed on which machine : Application server or DB machine ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked after we modified
`/opt/jdk-11.0.15.1/conf/security`
from:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

to:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves
```

Comment: Well ... you made yourself less secure by doing that!  You should upgrade MySQL and/or OpenSSL so that you don't need to tell Java to allow the deprecated TLSv1 or 1.1 protocols.  *"IETF has formally deprecated the TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 cryptographic protocols because they lack support for recommended cryptographic algorithms and mechanisms"* ([source](https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/116151/security/ietf-deprecates-tls-1-0-tls-1-1.html))

Comment: Although this works, I would argue this is the wrong solution as it compromises security. The better solution is to upgrade your MySQL server to a version that supports TLSv1.2 or higher.

Comment: Anther option: instead of changing Java , we can override jdbc url:
jdbc:mysql://<server>:<Port>/<DB>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : 
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version' ;


Output: Ssl_version TLSv1.2